# Creating permanent fixed buffer for CLHS lookup

Tags: buffers, common-lisp, slime, w3m

Suppose I open one window with a Common Lisp file in it, and a second window with SLIME REPL in it (using M-x slime or whatever). Now, doing `C-c C-d h` with point on a Common Lisp keyword brings up a window with the CLHS entry for that keyword (using w3m, and assuming everything has been configured correctly, but lets assume that is the case).

Now, I want the CLHS window to be set up, so that wherever I call `C-c C-d h`, either in the Lisp file window, or in the SLIME REPL window, the CLHS page comes up in the same window. This currently does not happen. I *am* using some code which I found on the Emacs wiki, [W3m: Browse url on other window](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/emacs-w3m#toc24), which helps but does not completely work. I think it works if only one window (besides the CLHS window) is open.

```
(setq browse-url-browser-function 'w3m-browse-url-other-window)

(defun w3m-browse-url-other-window (url &optional newwin)
  (let ((w3m-pop-up-windows t))
    (if (one-window-p) (split-window))
    (other-window 1)
    (w3m-browse-url url newwin)))
```

NOTE: This is probably a specific example of a more general question.

Answer (score 4):

I think the following should mostly do what you want

```
(defvar w3m-dedicated-window nil)

(defun w3m-browse-url-dedicated-window (url &optional new-session)
  (let ((w3m-pop-up-windows t))
    (if (and w3m-dedicated-window
             (window-live-p w3m-dedicated-window))
        (with-selected-window w3m-dedicated-window
          (w3m-browse-url url new-session))
      (split-window) ;; ugly as hell, but w3m-pop-up-windows is ignored...
      (other-window 1)
      (w3m-browse-url url new-session)
      (setq w3m-dedicated-window (selected-window))
      (set-window-dedicated-p w3m-dedicated-window t))))

(setq browse-url-browser-function 'w3m-browse-url-dedicated-window)
```

Using the dedicated window flag, it tries harder to keep the browser visible. And that dedicated window is reused as much as possible, whenever a new URL is browsed.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work. To start with, I just opened a Lisp file, and ran `C-c C-d h`. Emacs didn't open a new window; it just replaced the Lisp file with a CLHS entry. Then I tried opening a Lisp file, then run `M-x slime` which opened a second window. Then I ran `C-c C-d h` with point in the Lisp file window, and it replaced the Lisp file with a CLHS entry again. Also, when attempted to click on a link in the CLHS wndow, I get "Symbol's value as variable is void: "w3m-pop-up-windows". Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Ok, I partially take that back. Once a window containing a CLHS entry is open, the CLHS pages do seem to come up in the same window. But having the first CLHS entry come up in a window that is being used by something else is not ideal. Can this be fixed? Also, of course, one wants links to work...

Comment: No idea why `w3m-pop-up-windows` is undefined for you. It's a variable defined in `w3m.el` (and it works for me :)). You're right about the window being recycled. Unfortunately it looks like `w3m-pop-up-windows`, which should provide just that feature, is ignored when w3m is called non-interactively, as is the case here. I guess using `(split-window)` as in your initial code could work. It's a bit ugly though

Comment: Ok, just fyi, I don't get notified if you don't add a @ in front. Can you suggest a possible reworking of the code using (split-window)?

Comment: @FaheemMitha yep, edited my code to reflect that. There ought to be a better solution though :(